# using printf function for repeated patterns

Tags: awk, printf

I have codes which append the patterns into text file w.r.t. the user's input as follows;

```
echo -n "WHICH STATIONS?"
read station
awk -v input="$station" '
 BEGIN {
        n = split(tolower(input), user)     
         pattern=  "force %-4s npos 0. .0001\n"       
    }
    {print}
    /<< write after this line >>/ {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
             printf pattern, user[i]
        exit
    }
' ./data > data_2
```

let assume user's input `abcd ab12` then commands append below lines;

```
force abcd npos 0. .0001
force ab12 npos 0. .0001
```

I need to add `epos` and `upos` strings for each input for separate lines as follows (for same inputs as above example);

```
force abcd npos 0. .0001
force abcd epos 0. .0001
force abcd upos 0. .0001
force ab12 npos 0. .0001
force ab12 epos 0. .0001
force ab12 upos 0. .0001
```

How can I modify the `pattern` option to append these lines into the data file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
pattern = "force %1$-4s npos 0. .0001\n" \
          "force %1$-4s epos 0. .0001\n" \
          "force %1$-4s upos 0. .0001\n"
[...]
printf pattern, user[i]
```

Like for the `printf(3)` of the GNU `libc`, `%<n>$s` in GNU `awk`, refers to the *n*th argument after the format.

Portably:

```
pattern = "force %-4s npos 0. .0001\n" \
          "force %-4s epos 0. .0001\n" \
          "force %-4s upos 0. .0001\n"
[...]
printf pattern, j=user[i], j, j
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that allow to specify dynamicaly the list of "Xpos"

```
echo -n "WHICH STATIONS?"
read station

awk -v input="$station" -v 'xpos=npos epos upos' '
 BEGIN {
    n = split(tolower(input), user)
    m = split( xpos, Pos) 
    pattern=  "force %-4s %s 0. .0001\n"       
    }
  1
  /<< write after this line >>/ {
     for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
        for (j=1;j<=m;j++)
           printf pattern, user[i],Pos[j]
     exit
     }
' ./data > data_2
```